# Why doesn't GRUB detect my Installation?

Tags: grub2

I just reinstalled GRUB on my computer but it does not detect my kubuntu partition (`/dev/sda1` ). Only the memtest+ entry appears in GRUB menu. My grub menu version is 1.99~rc1-13ubuntu3. Please help me!!

This my output using boot_info_script.sh:

```
              Boot Info Script 0.60    from 17 May 2011
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for ?? on this drive.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:  
Operating System:  Ubuntu 11.04
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sdb1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:   According to the info in the boot sector, sdb1 starts 
                   at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                   sdb1 starts at sector 63.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   484,278,271   484,276,224  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         484,280,318   488,396,799     4,116,482   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         484,280,320   488,396,799     4,116,480  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Drive: sdb ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004511744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486 cylinders, total 7821312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                  63     7,807,589     7,807,527   b W95 FAT32
```

"blkid" output: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        b8a57e51-613f-45c6-a7f0-5dd74e62e2fd   ext4       
/dev/sda5        09d61304-c671-4481-b7c4-acb24b6c8c7d   swap       
/dev/sdb1        8220-55E0                              vfat
```

================================ Mount points: =================================

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /media/8220-55E0         vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=999,gid=999,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)
```

=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8a57e51-613f-45c6-a7f0-5dd74e62e2fd
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(/dev/sda,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b8a57e51-613f-45c6-a7f0-5dd74e62e2fd
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b8a57e51-613f-45c6-a7f0-5dd74e62e2fd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=09d61304-c671-4481-b7c4-acb24b6c8c7d none            swap    sw                0       0
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

```
          GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 116.134162903 = 124.698107904  boot/grub/core.img                             1
 116.522464752 = 125.115043840  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 207.804080963 = 223.127932928  boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic              2
   1.727539062 = 1.854930944    boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic               3
 205.950504303 = 221.137670144  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic                 1
 116.133281708 = 124.697161728  boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic                  1
 207.804080963 = 223.127932928  initrd.img                                     2
   1.727539062 = 1.854930944    initrd.img.old                                 3
 205.950504303 = 221.137670144  vmlinuz                                        1
 116.133281708 = 124.697161728  vmlinuz.old                                    1
```

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

```
00000000  2f 73 63 73 69 2f 6c 69  62 69 73 63 73 69 2e 6b  |/scsi/libiscsi.k|
00000010  6f 0a 2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d  6f 64 75 6c 65 73 2f 32  |o./lib/modules/2|
00000020  2e 36 2e 33 32 2d 32 31  2d 67 65 6e 65 72 69 63  |.6.32-21-generic|
00000030  2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c 2f  64 72 69 76 65 72 73 2f  |/kernel/drivers/|
00000040  73 63 73 69 2f 6c 69 62  69 73 63 73 69 5f 74 63  |scsi/libiscsi_tc|
00000050  70 2e 6b 6f 0a 2f 6c 69  62 2f 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65  |p.ko./lib/module|
00000060  73 2f 32 2e 36 2e 33 32  2d 32 31 2d 67 65 6e 65  |s/2.6.32-21-gene|
00000070  72 69 63 2f 6b 65 72 6e  65 6c 2f 64 72 69 76 65  |ric/kernel/drive|
00000080  72 73 2f 73 63 73 69 2f  6c 69 62 73 61 73 0a 2f  |rs/scsi/libsas./|
00000090  6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64 75  6c 65 73 2f 32 2e 36 2e  |lib/modules/2.6.|
000000a0  33 32 2d 32 31 2d 67 65  6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b 65  |32-21-generic/ke|
000000b0  72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72 69  76 65 72 73 2f 73 63 73  |rnel/drivers/scs|
000000c0  69 2f 6c 69 62 73 61 73  2f 6c 69 62 73 61 73 2e  |i/libsas/libsas.|
000000d0  6b 6f 0a 2f 6c 69 62 2f  6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 73 2f  |ko./lib/modules/|
000000e0  32 2e 36 2e 33 32 2d 32  31 2d 67 65 6e 65 72 69  |2.6.32-21-generi|
000000f0  63 2f 6b 65 72 6e 65 6c  2f 64 72 69 76 65 72 73  |c/kernel/drivers|
00000100  2f 73 63 73 69 2f 6c 69  62 73 72 70 2e 6b 6f 0a  |/scsi/libsrp.ko.|
00000110  2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  75 6c 65 73 2f 32 2e 36  |/lib/modules/2.6|
00000120  2e 33 32 2d 32 31 2d 67  65 6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b  |.32-21-generic/k|
00000130  65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72  69 76 65 72 73 2f 73 63  |ernel/drivers/sc|
00000140  73 69 2f 6c 70 66 63 0a  2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  |si/lpfc./lib/mod|
00000150  75 6c 65 73 2f 32 2e 36  2e 33 32 2d 32 31 2d 67  |ules/2.6.32-21-g|
00000160  65 6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b  65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72  |eneric/kernel/dr|
00000170  69 76 65 72 73 2f 73 63  73 69 2f 6c 70 66 63 2f  |ivers/scsi/lpfc/|
00000180  6c 70 66 63 2e 6b 6f 0a  2f 6c 69 62 2f 6d 6f 64  |lpfc.ko./lib/mod|
00000190  75 6c 65 73 2f 32 2e 36  2e 33 32 2d 32 31 2d 67  |ules/2.6.32-21-g|
000001a0  65 6e 65 72 69 63 2f 6b  65 72 6e 65 6c 2f 64 72  |eneric/kernel/dr|
000001b0  69 76 65 72 73 2f 73 63  73 69 2f 6d 65 67 00 fe  |ivers/scsi/meg..|
000001c0  ff ff 82 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 d0 3e 00 00 00  |............>...|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

To be able to see for which directory Grub2 (v1.99) looks for, install "unlzma".

Comment: Did you run `sudo update grub`?

Comment: yeah, i did it..
But it does not detect my ubuntu partition:root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

Comment: What filesystem is Kubuntu installed on? How did you install Kubuntu and GRUB?

Comment: Please download the boot_info_script, run it, and provide the output of it. http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript

Comment: my kubuntu filesystem is ext4, I install it using live cd.. Before this happen my grub menu is missing so i decided to reinstall the grub menu using live cd.. Also now i am running on live cd to browse the internet.

Comment: reinstall grub2 using synaptic manager. Then update-grub

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!